# How to resume song from YouTube on different pages

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am Developing Windows Phone Application. I am playing a song from YouTube on first page. I want to ask that when when we pause a song on page and then if we move to another page then the song should resume from point where i pause it on before page. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to play song using bacground audio player in windows phone, it could help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: It is for Static Song.. Bt my song comming from youtube